# Print output to screen differs from output to file

Tags: perl

Using the `print` operator to write a key/value array to an external javascript file generates different output than printing to the screen, and, despite my best efforts, I can't figure out why. Specifically, when printing to the screen, as expected, my Perl script outputs:

```
var genusSpecies={"Adam's Needle (Yucca filamentosa)":["Adam's Needle (Yucca filamentosa)1.jpg","._Adam's Needle (Yucca filamentosa)2.jpg"...
```

When printing to an external JavaScript file, however, dot-underscore `._` is improperly prepended to both the keys and values of the array, outputting:

```
var genusSpecies={"._Adam's Needle (Yucca filamentosa)":["._Adam's Needle (Yucca filamentosa)1.jpg","._Adam's Needle (Yucca filamentosa)2.jpg"...
```

Here's my Perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use JSON::PP;

use English;  ## use names rather than symbols for special variables

my $dir = './Plants1024';

opendir my $dfh, $dir or die "Can't open $dir: $OS_ERROR";
my %genus_species;  ## store matching entries in a hash

for my $file (readdir $dfh)
{
    next unless $file =~ /.(jpe?g|png)$/i;  ## entry must have jpg, jpeg, or png extension, case insensitive
    my $genus = $file =~ s/\d*\.(?i)(jpe?g|png)(?-i)$//r;
    push(@{$genus_species{$genus}}, $file);  ## push to array, the @{} is to cast the single entry to a reference to a list

}

@{$genus_species{$_}} = sort @{$genus_species{$_}}
   for keys(%genus_species);

my $str = (JSON::PP->new->utf8->canonical->encode(\%genus_species));  ## define array in Javascript outputting elements containing image file names

print "var genusSpecies=", $str;  ## Inserted this line to test "print" output... prints properly WITHOUT adding "._"

my $filename = './Plants1024/PhotoArray.js';

 open(my $fh, '>', $filename) or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";
 print $fh "var genusSpecies=", $str;  ## saves JavaScript key/value array in external JavaScript file, BUT improperly prepends "._" to both keys and values 
 close $fh;
```

Interestingly, only when executing this Perl script on my Raspberry Pi4 does the output to the screen versus the file differ, adding the `._` to array keys/values in written files.

On my Mac, as expected, the screen and file outputs are the same. More importantly, `._` is not improperly prepended when executing my Perl script on the Mac.

Perhaps the spaces in the array keys/values are causing this behavior, but why only on the Raspberry Pi4 and not the Mac? Please advise.

Comment: Re "*Perhaps the spaces in the array keys/values are causing this behavior*", You aren't printing keys or value, you are printing two strings. 
If what you say is true, this would be a serious bug in Perl's or Raspberry's IO system. Do you get the same problem with just: `my $qfn = './Plants1024/PhotoArray.js'; open(my $fh, '>', $qfn)   or die("open \"$qfn\": $!\n");  print $fh 'genusSpecies={"Adam'."\n";`

Comment: btw, the name of the language is Perl, not PERL. It's not an acronym.

Comment: ikegami... Here's the file output of your above code: genusSpecies={"Adam

Comment: ok, in your original program, replace `print $fh "var genusSpecies=", $str;` with `my $s = substr($str, 0, 100); print $fh "var genusSpecies=", $s . unpack("H*", $s);` and provide the output

Comment: Here's the output: var genusSpecies={"._Adam's Needle (Yucca filamentosa)":["._Adam's Needle (Yucca filamentosa)1.jpg","._Adam's Needle 7b222e5f4164616d2773204e6565646c65202859756363612066696c616d656e746f736129223a5b222e5f4164616d2773204e6565646c65202859756363612066696c616d656e746f736129312e6a7067222c222e5f4164616d2773204e6565646c6520

Comment: Ok, it has nothing to do with writing to a file since it already contains the `._` before the `print`. (If you don't see `._` on the console when printing to the console, *that* would be a bug, but I'm going to assume you made a mistake for now).

Comment: Can you find out at what step they first appear? Does `$file` contain them, or is JSON::PP adding them?

Comment: Why not start by checking if the files actually exist by using `ls -a`.

Comment: So where's the ._ coming from? And why is it outputted only when my Perl script is executed on my Raspberry Pi4, and not my Mac? Any suggestions how to get rid of it?

Comment: Aw but the PERL version has such a long and venerable history! :)  Surely you know the backronym Practical Extraction and Reporting Language.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, `ls` hides files starting with `.`

```
$ ls -1
'Adam'\''s Needle (Yucca filamentosa)'

$ ls -a1
.
..
'._Adam'\''s Needle (Yucca filamentosa)'
'Adam'\''s Needle (Yucca filamentosa)'
```

This is leading you to think you have no such files, but they exist.

`readdir` doesn't ignore such files. You can address this by adding

```perl
next if $file =~ /^\./;
```

While `readdir` doesn't ignore files with leading `.`, it might ignore files with a leading `._` on a Mac. The Mac creates such files to store extra information about the similarly-named file. I'm guessing the directory you are reading was created on a Mac.

Comment: ikegami... Your "next if" statement solves the problem... Thank you!!!

Comment: The `._` files are how MacOS stores the resource fork for files when on a file system that doesn't support alternate streams.  I find them highly annoying and most detestable.